# EF Core: SaveChangesAsync, MARS, and "New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have a Web API using EF Core 2.0 on a SQL Server 2017 backend.

I recently noticed we had never enabled Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) in the connection string. So I turned it on, hoping to get a little better performance.

At first, everything seemed fine. However, shortly, our calls to `dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` began to fail with the message "New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session".

Generally, this message occurs when someone tries to save changes inside a loop. I am not doing that - the failing API call inserted a single item into the database, saved changes, and returned.

I checked that everything `async` was being correctly `awaited`. I tried adding an explicit `Wait()` call to my `SaveChangesAsync`. Nothing worked.

I turned MARS back off and everything works again. Does anyone know what could have caused this?

Comment: Show us the code that couse the problem, how are you saving the items? one `SaveChangesAsync` async is enagh the could exist outside the loop. without showing that code we cant determind the problem. and using `Multiple Active Result` without having a good eye on how many connection that is open is really bad. Default i think that you could have 100, you could also have more if you specify it in connection string

Comment: Please post a [mcve].